# Ruby: bracket notation for immediate call of returned procedure

Tags: ruby, proc

In Ruby, when I'm doing an immediate callback of a returned Proc, I normally use `#call`:

```
def multiplier(factor)
  Proc.new { |number| factor * number }
end

puts multiplier(10).call(5) # 50
```

But I've just run across this bracket shorthand, which has the same result as far as I can see:

```
def multiplier(factor)
  Proc.new { |number| factor * number }
end

puts multiplier(10)[5] # 50
```

This strikes me as very similar to JavaScript's immediate call of a returned function:

```
const multiplier = (factor) => (number) => factor * number;

console.log(multiplier(10)(5)); // 50
```

But I've never seen the syntax before, and I can't seem to find it documented anywhere. Is this just syntax sugar for using `#call`, or is there more to it? And I can't seem to find any doc on it. Is there some somewhere?

Comment: See some documentation here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: You can also use `.()` as a shorthand for call (the preceding dot is needed) to get even closer to the Javascript version. Personally I always shied away from the brackets form

Comment: @maxpleaner I didn't even know the brackets form existed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I've never seen the syntax before,

I would advise you to get a better tutorial. Most tutorials teach arrays and hashes *very* early on, where this exact syntax is explained.

> and I can't seem to find it documented anywhere.

[The documentation for the `Proc#[]` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D) is in [the documentation of the `Proc` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html), just like all other methods.

> Is this just syntax sugar for using `#call`

No, it is not syntactic sugar for `#call`. It is syntactic sugar for `#[]`.

Again, this *really* should have been explained very early on in any tutorial:

```ruby
foo[bar, baz, quux]

# is syntactic sugar for 

foo.[](bar, baz, quux)
```

> or is there more to it?

No, there is nothing more to it.

> And I can't seem to find any doc on it. Is there some somewhere?

That fact that `foo[bar]` is syntactic sugar for `foo.[](bar)` is generally explained in any introductory tutorial either in the chapter about message sends or in the chapter about operators, maybe also in the chapter about arrays or hashes (because that is the most common use case).

[Again, I am quite surprised that you have encountered higher-order programming with `Proc`s, yet have never seen an array or hash before, or basic Ruby syntax. That seems a really strange way to order teaching / learning of concepts.]

It is described *very clearly* in the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) chapter 11.3 *Method invocation expressions*, subchapter 11.3.1 *General description*, section *Semantics*, clause  *b)*:

> An *indexing-method-invocation* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate the *primary-expression*. Let **O** be the resulting value.
> 2. If the *indexing-argument-list* is present, construct a list of arguments from the *indexing-argument-list* as described in 11.3.2. Let **L** be the resulting list.
> 3. If the *indexing-argument-list* is omitted, Create an empty list of arguments **L**.
> 4. Invoke the method `[]` on **O** with **L** as the list of arguments. The value of the *indexing-method-invocation* is the resulting value.

Of particular interest here is subclause *4)* which explains how the syntactic sugar is desugared, namely that `O[L]` means invoking the method `[]` on `O` with `L` as arguments, or in other words that `O[L]` is syntactic sugar for `O.[](L)`.

[The ruby/spec is unfortunately not quite as clear.](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/method_spec.rb#L1832-L1862)

[And the YARV documentation hides it away in a paragraph without an explicit heading](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names):

> Additionally, methods for element reference and assignment may be defined: `[]` and `[]=` respectively. Both can take one or more arguments, and element reference can take none.
>
> ```ruby
> class C
>   def [](a, b)
>     puts a + b
>   end
>
>   def []=(a, b, c)
>     puts a * b + c
>   end
> end
>
> obj = C.new
>
> obj[2, 3]     # prints "5"
> obj[2, 3] = 4 # prints "10"
> ```

It is documented [in the first edition of *Programming Ruby* by "PragDave" Dave Thomas and Andy Hunt](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) in the chapter on [*Operator Expressions*](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S1):

> More useful is the fact that classes that you write can participate in operator expressions just as if they were built-in objects. For example, we might want to be able to extract a number of seconds of music from the middle of a song. We could using the indexing operator ```[]`'' to specify the music to be extracted.
>
> ```ruby
> class Song
>   def [](fromTime, toTime)
>     result = Song.new(self.title + " [extract]",
>                       self.artist,
>                       toTime - fromTime)
>     result.setStartTime(fromTime)
>     result
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> This code fragment extends class `Song` with the method ```[]`'', which takes two parameters (a start time and an end time). It returns a new song, with the music clipped to the given interval. We could then play the introduction to a song with code such as:
>
> ```ruby
> aSong[0, 0.15].play
> ```

This exact same chapter is also present in [the second edition on page 82](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby-2nd-edition/), except the names of the method parameters now follow standard Ruby naming conventions.

I don't have access to my paper copy of the 4th edition at the moment, but I know it is in there as well.

I am also sure it is documented in [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro "matz" Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177), but I don't have that copy handy either.

If you prefer looking at source code, here is [the source code of `Proc#[]`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/proc.rb#L226) in [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/), it is as simple as it gets:

> ```ruby
> alias_method :[], :call
> ```

Similarly, here is [the code](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/java/org/truffleruby/core/proc/ProcNodes.java#L194) in [TruffleRuby](https://www.graalvm.org/ruby/):

> ```java
> @CoreMethod(names = { "call", "[]", "yield" }, rest = true, needsBlock = true, alwaysInlined = true)
> public abstract static class CallNode extends AlwaysInlinedMethodNode {
>     // …
> }
> ```

And [the code](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyProc.java#L270) in [JRuby](https://jruby.org/):

> ```java
> @JRubyMethod(name = {"call", "[]", "yield", "==="}, rest = true, omit = true)
> public final IRubyObject call(ThreadContext context, IRubyObject[] args, Block blockCallArg) {
>     // …
> }
> ```

> Is this just syntax sugar for using `#call`

As explained above, it is not, but it might be interesting to know that there *is* syntactic sugar for `#call`, namely `.()`. So,

```ruby
foo.(bar, baz, quux)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```ruby
foo.call(bar, baz, quux)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and interesting answer, Jörg, and for all the doc references. What I've been missing is that `Proc` has its own implementation of `#[]`, distinct from the array and hash implementations. Matz's book gives a good explanation (Sec. 6.5.2): "The Proc class also defines the array access operator to work the same way as `call`. This means that you can invoke a proc or lambda using a syntax that is like method invocation, where parentheses have been replaced with square brackets."

Comment: You can always just ask Ruby, she is very friendly: `some_proc = ->{}; where_does_this_method_come_from = some_proc.method(:[]).owner #=> Proc`. That's the power of a fully reflective language.